# pass a variable as a script in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I've got the below play wherein I'm trying to stop WAS instances on an AIX server.

```
  ---
  - hosts: all
  vars_files:
     - /etc/ansible/conf/var.yml
  tasks:
    - name: stop websphere instances
      script: {{ was_script }} {{ item }}
      with_items: "{{ was_inst }}"
```

The was_script and was_inst are listed as variable in var.yml. Now if I hardcode the script instead of was_script it works. But it's not working if I call it as a variable. 
It says it's a YAML syntax error, but I can't seem to figure out what the error is.

Comment: Paste the error message, please. There's an answer in it.

Comment: `Error! Syntax Error while loading YAML.`

`The offending line appears to be:`
` - name: stop websphere instances`
   `script: {{ was_script }} {{ item }}`
                                      `^ here`

Comment: And there's an explanation what you should do on the next line.

Comment: `We could be wrong but this one looks like it might be an issue with missing quotes. Always quote template expression brackets when they start a value.`
But I've written with_items with the correct syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arrow `^ here` is pointing to the `script: {{ was_script }} {{ item }}` line.
You should quote it `script: "{{ was_script }} {{ item }}"`, because it starts with braces.
There's a note about [YAML gotchas](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/YAMLSyntax.html#gotchas) in the docs.

Comment: Thanks very much; That helped, although I ran into a new error. The playbook now fails saying that the script is not found. For some weird reason it's searching in /etc/ansible/playbooks instead of the directory I mentioned in the var.yml
`"failed": true, "msg": "file or module does not exist: /etc/ansible/playbooks/[u\"/tmp/stop_was.sh'"]")`

Comment: I ran it using the debug and here's what I found:
`Debugger invoked
(debug) p vars['was_script']
[u'/tmp/stop_was.sh']
(debug) vars['was_script'] = '/tmp/stop_was,sh'
(debug) p vars['was_script']
'/tmp/stop_was.sh'`

and it ran fine after that.